# how to extract description details from media (audio) file in java

Tags: java

I am writing a java program where , I need audio track information like name, artists, rating etc descriptions just like windows media player gets the information.Can anybody guide me which API's to go for ?

Comment: I have came across Xuggler for Video related operations.. dont know whether it will work for audio or not. I suggest you should give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this [Java ID3](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/) check it out.

Here are some more.

[javamusictag](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/QuickStart.html)

[magicmp3](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic)